# Java NIO for peer to peer network solution

Tags: java, sockets, nio, p2p

i am using java NIO to make a sample p2p network and get some trouble with it.

Here is the scenario

1 node has both client and server functions. I use NIO for server function and normal socketchannel for client

I run the NIO server function and client function in 2 separated threads for each node.
NIO server uses ServerSocketChannel and selector

NIO client will create a SocketChannel and connect to ServerSocketChannel of the node it want to connect.

My question is: Currently, sender and receiver use separated ports. How can I merge them to use only 1 for both sending and receiving ?

This is code for receiver

```
 public Receiver(short port) {
    try {
        ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel
                .open();
        serverSocketChannel.socket().setReuseAddress(true);
        serverSocketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
        serverSocketChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
        this.channel = serverSocketChannel;

        Selector selector = Selector.open();
        channel.configureBlocking(false);
        channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

        p2pProtocol = new Protocol(port);
        while (true) {
            int readyChannels = selector.select();
            if (readyChannels == 0) {
                // Accept channel is busy
                continue;
            }

            Set<SelectionKey> selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys();

            Iterator<SelectionKey> keyIterator = selectedKeys.iterator();

            while (keyIterator.hasNext()) {

                SelectionKey key = keyIterator.next();

                if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                    // a connection request from other node
                    acceptKey(selector, key);
                } else if (key.isConnectable()) {
                    // a connection was established with a remote server.
                    Log.writeLog("Connectable");

                } else if (key.isReadable()) {
                    // a channel is ready for reading
                    receive(key);

                } else if (key.isWritable()) {
                    // a channel is ready for writing
                    write(key);
                }

                keyIterator.remove();
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And this is for sender:

```
public Sender(InetAddress address, short remotePort, short serverPort) {
    this.listeningPort = serverPort;

    // Create socket connection
    try {
        socket = new Socket(address, remotePort);
        out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(
                socket.getInputStream()));
        active = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.writeLog("No I/O");
    }
}

public boolean getStatus()
{
    return active;
}

public Message sendMessage(MsgType type) {
    Message m = MessageFactory.craftRequestMessage(type,
            listeningPort, false);

    try {
        byte[] send = Conversion.serializeMessageToBytes(m).array();
        out.flush();
        out.write(send);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.writeLog(e.getMessage());
    }

    return m;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'remember'? Your question is not clear.

Comment: I mean, it's similar to A send a "Join" request to B. B accepts and records that A with port 8880 is one of its neighbor in the network.

Comment: So what's the question? NB select() returning zero doesn't mean 'accept channel is busy': it means the exact opposite.

Comment: I'm really sorry, it's a little confuse. I want to ask how can i merge my sender and receiver so they can use only 1 port to send and receive.

Comment: If your server is also a client it's impossible.